# When will variables be removed by optimization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, volatile

I'm working with threads and I have question about how the compilers are allowed to optimize the following code:

```
void MyClass::f(){
    Parent* p = this->m_parent;
    this->m_done = true;
    p->function();
}
```

It is very important that `p` (on the stack or in a register) is used to call the function instead of `this->m_parent`. Since as soon as `m_done` becomes `true` then `this` may be deleted from another thread if it happens to run its cleanup pass (I have had actual crashes due to this), in which case `m_parent` could contain garbage, but the thread stack/registers would be intact.

My initial testing on GCC/Linux shows that I don't have a race condition but I would like to know if this will be the case on other compilers as well?

Is this a case for *gulp* `volatile`? I've looked at [What kinds of optimizations does 'volatile' prevent in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604569/what-kinds-of-optimizations-does-volatile-prevent-in-c) and [Is 'volatile' needed in this multi-threaded C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612505/is-volatile-needed-in-this-multi-threaded-c-code/3612652#3612652) but I didn't feel like either of them applied to my problem.

I feel uneasy relying on this as I'm unsure what the compiler is allowed to do here. I see the following cases:

- No/Beneficial optimization, the pointer in `this->m_parent` is stored on the stack/register and this value is later used to call `function()` this is wanted behavior.
- Compiler removes `p` but `this->m_parent` is by chance available in a register already and the compiler uses this for the call to `function()` would work but be unreliable between compilers. This is bad as it could expose bugs moving to a different platform/compiler version.
- Compiler removes `p` and reads `this->m_parent` before the call to `function()`, this creates a race condition which I can't have.

Could some one please shed some light on what the compiler is allowed to do here?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that `this->m_done` is a `std::atomic<bool>` and I'm using C++11.

Comment: The `register` keyword would do what I want if the compiler would respect it...

Comment: this is not a problem of volatile / register. It's a problem of re-ordering. The compiler is allowed to set m_done to true before he actually loads m_parent.

Comment: Also `volatile` will force a memory read from the buss, which isn't really what (even though it probably could be used for solving my problem). I just want to tell the compiler "Pretty please keep this value in a register `cause it's going to dissapear soon and I need a copy"

Comment: @TobiasLangner `register` and a memory barrier would do it I guess but compiler won't necessarily respect `register` :(

Comment: I am inclined to say that the compiler is right and your code is broken. And even if your code can be made technically legal, it seems too tricky for comfort.

Comment: register doesn't help and is not required. You need a value in p - that's enough. And it needs to be there before m_done is true.

Comment: I believe that the proposed atomic change is enough and the use of the variable `p` is not needed at all. Depending on compiler `this` will be already put on the stack or in register and the memory pointed by it is not needed to retrieve the pointer. But if the `function` is virtual then this code is not safe at all, because it relies on the existence of the memory pointed by `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work perfectly as written in C++11 if `m_done` is `std::atomic<bool>`. The read of `m_parent` is *sequenced-before* the write to `m_done` which will synchronize with a hypothetical read of `m_done` in another thread that is *sequenced-before* a hypothetical write to `m_parent`. Taken together, that means that the standard guarantees that this thread's read of `m_parent` *happens-before* the other thread's write.

Comment: Thank you, that sells me! And I'll end this with a quote from Mc Hammer: "Na-na-na-na can't touch `this`!"   (sorry I had to, I just found it hilarious, I know, I'm terribad)

Comment: @EmilyB.: Notice the lack of upvotes :) I think you were too quick to accept an answer (and dismiss Pete's answer); I'm tempted to believe it's correct, but I don't have any reference to indicate so. You might want to keep on checking the answers here just in case.

Comment: "Perfectly as written" was meant in reference to the memory ordering only: the code is data-race-free.

Comment: I suppose that implies that the compiler may still optimize out the variable completely? I just realized I typoed the original code. `m_done` is a part of `m_parent` so m_parent has to be read into a register before m_done is written (`m_parent->m_done= true`) so it'll be in a register on all the platforms I care about (x86-64) yes?

Comment: The compiler can do anything it wants, as long is the value used for `p` is the value that was read from `m_parent` *before* the write to `m_done`. (Realistically yes, it will store `p` in a register - but don't worry about implementation details. Memory ordering is confusing enough without adding more detail ;)

Comment: I think you are overly obsessed by registers. "this" will probably be in a register. But this is no problem. m_done will not be in a register - it has to be written to memory. p can be in a register or not, but it does not matter. It is initialized from memory (m_parent) and then used to call p() again. No problem here.

Comment: I'm not obsessed by the registers :) I just worry that the compiler will emit instructions to read `this` from memory (in order to call `this->m_parent->function`) *after* the memory barrier (when it might have already been invalidated) because it decided that storing `p` on the stack (or a register) would be unnecessary.

Comment: he's not allowed due to the memory barrier. That's what it's for. As I said - it's not about register, it's about re-ordering

Answer (score 1):

You might run into a re-ordering problem. Check memory barriers to solve this problem. Place it so that the loading of p and the setting of m_done is done in exactly that order (place it between both instructions) and you should be fine.

Implementations are available in C++11 and boost.

Comment: Actually, `this->m_done` is a `std::atomic<bool>` isn't that an automatic memory barrier?

Comment: according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic - yes. See the second paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

Um, some other thread might delete the object out from under you while you're in one of its member functions? Undefined behavior. Plain and simple.

Comment: Behaviour is perfectly defined as long as I don't touch `this` after it happens, the stack and register contents are valid and well defined.

Comment: @EmilyB. - no, that's a heuristic. The C++ language definition does not require this to work; that's what "undefined behavior" means.

Comment: @Mehrdad - you want me to cite the place in the language definition that doesn't say that this has to work? Simple: the entire standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Well, you're claiming that `this` for member functions is treated differently from regular pointers in free functions. It's plausible, but that doesn't make it true. What makes you think it's the case (and that this is UB)?

Comment: @Mehrdad - show me where the standard says that a member function will work correctly after the end of the lifetime of the object that it was called on.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Which part of the standard says that a free function will work correctly after the end of the lifetime of an object it has received a pointer to? It's probably the same section.

Comment: @Mehrdad - surely you understand that member functions are not the same as free functions. If they were, they wouldn't need a different name.

Comment: Is it undefined behavior to call a member function in the destructor? Object lifetime ends when the destructor starts (3.8p1).

Comment: @PeteBecker: They're both still functions, though. Can you point me to the part of the standard that states that *this* in particular is one of their differences between member and free functions? Just because they have a different name doesn't mean that *everything* is different about them. For all I know, the only difference between (non-virtual) member and free functions could be in their abilities to access `private`/`protected` variables, and ***nothing more***. If you're claiming otherwise then you should cite the part of the C++ standard that explains the difference you're referring to.

Comment: In fact, [here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3151000/541686) that indicates you're wrong. Read [**this**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html) too.

Comment: Um, citing an answer that says, without authority, that `delete this` is well defined does not prove anything. It rests on the same assumptions as deleting from another thread: that if you don't touch any data members on the way out things are okay. There's nothing in the standard that says that.

Comment: 12.7p4: "Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction (12.6.2)." 3.8p1: "The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when: if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or the storage which the object occupies is reused or released." The standard does define behavior for invoking member functions after the object lifetime has ended. There are, however, *many* actions that are explicitly undefined behavior after the destructor completes mentioned all through 12.7.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Your answer doesn't point to any authoritative source about the differences between member and free functions either, and yet you thought "surely I understand" the difference. Well, same thing here.

Comment: @Mehrdad - the starting point is that if the standard doesn't say what happens, then the behavior is undefined. That may sound like a tautology, but it's the definition of "undefined behavior". If you think the behavior of this code (or of `delete this`, which is essentially equivalent) is well defined, point out the part or parts of the standard that say what happens. Asserting that member functions are just like free functions in this regard is merely hand waving.

Comment: @PeteBecker Am I to take your comments as indicating that you do not believe `delete this` to have defined behavior? I've seen quite a few statements to the contrary in the past by several committee members, including you. Has something changed in C++11 to make `delete this` undefined?

Comment: @PeteBecker: Ok, where does the standard say what happens for **free** functions with pointer arguments that get deleted? If you can't point me to a specific location (which you seem to be refusing to do) then by your reasoning that must be UB too??

Comment: @Casey - you have **never** seen a statement from me that `delete this` has well-defined behavior according to the language definition. I have never thought that that was the case.

Comment: @Mehrdad - you're trying to change the subject. My assertion was that the behavior is undefined; you claim that it's well defined. As you said, "[citation needed]".

Comment: @PeteBecker: Uh, no, I'm not changing the subject -- you're just ignoring the problem with your reasoning. If you can't point me to a part of the standard that talks about how `delete p;` behaves in *free* functions, how can you claim it behaves differently in *member* functions, where `p` *simply happens* to be `this`? If the standard doesn't differentiate between them then there obviously they're either both UB or both well-defined.

Comment: @Mehrdad - huh? Let's start at the beginning. Is it your position that the standard defines the behavior of `delete this`? (It seems like that's the root of your position). If so, where in the standard does it tell you that? Again, "[citation needed]".

Comment: Here's a golden oldie from 1995: ["...the answer is yes, delete this is valid, and compilers should support it."](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/CUJ/1995/9508/becker/becker.htm). [Here's an answer from 2012 in which you discuss the effect of `delete this` without mentioning undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12100365/923854). In any case, we should probably all take this to discussion, or post a new question.

Comment: @Casey - good catch (the first one); what can I say? We were all young and foolish at one time. `<g>` And, of course, in 1995 there was no C++ standard. The second one, of course, has nothing to do with this discussion; it involved deleting a stack object.

Comment: In any case, 12.7p4 allows *calling* member functions of an object after the end of its lifetime, if it's possible for such a function invocation to complete without undefined behavior, I can't see how a member function called *before* the end of the object's lifetime and returning after the end would behave differently.

Comment: @PeteBecker: OK, let's restart. **Yes**, I'm saying `delete this` is valid. But I'm telling you **no**, you **don't** need the standard to mention this explicitly, because `this` is a pointer, and **just as for any other pointer**, the standard explicitly says that `delete p;` works on **any** pointer `p` that was allocated with `new`. As far as I know, the standard **never differentiates** between the cases where `p == this` and `p != this`. You're claiming `delete p;` is invalid in the special case where `p == this`, which the standard never claims to be true, hence you need a citation.